# Cannot read .kv file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Every time i run the program i gives me BLACK SCREEN.. 
Meterials:
Python - 3.4.4
PyCharm - 2016.3.3
kivy - 1.10.0
and Windows 8 (64bit)

(i am just a beginner trying to test if kivy works fine using someones code, please help me fix this issue)

**Below is the .py code**

import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyWidget(Widget):

```
pass
```

class MyWidgetApp(App):

```
  def build (self):
       return MyWidget()



if __name__=="__main__":

   MyWidgetApp().run()
```

*****Below is the .kv file*****

## :kivy 1.10.0

:

```
Button:

    text: "Hello"
    font_size: 32
    color: .8,9,0,1
    pos: 0, 100
    size: 100, 50

Button:
    text: "World"
    font_size: 32
    color: .8,9,0,1
    pos: 100, 0
    size: 100, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy will look for a file named: *mywidget.kv* in your working directory... If you change the name/location of your kv file you'll be fine. It looks for that name because this is part of your class name (**MyWidget**App)

In any case, I don't see that you relate to your **MyWidget** in the .kv file

try something simple:

```
<MyWidget>:
     Label:
         text: "Hi!!!"
```